# Is there an equivalent to POSIX Regex [:punct:] in PCRE?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have the following regex in PHP:

```
/[[:punct:]-]/
```

To test a password entry for a special character. `MyPassword!` would be valid in this case.

Is there a PCRE shorthand character class for this? To avoid the POSIX variant? Would like to do something like this:

```
preg_match('/\SPECIAL-/', 'MyPassword!')
```

Comment: Do you want to match punctuation proper? Then use `\p{P}`. `[[:punct:]]` is `[\p{P}\p{S}]`

Comment: Oh, I see, now too. Thanks for the hint. Special character != punctuation sign. Actually, the point is that at least one special character should be given.

Comment: So, choose what you mean by "special character" and use it in your regex.